# How to pass codebehind information into javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a button in my updatepanel and I'm trying to call a javascript function (after it does it's processing).

I put this code inside the `Page_Load`:

```
    Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "modalScript", "jsModal('" + msg + "');", True)
    keywordSearch.Attributes.Add("onclick", "jsModal('" + msg + "');")
```

Client Side javascript:

```
function showModal(msg) {
    $("#modal-content, #modal-background, #modal-close").toggleClass("active");
    var returnString = msg;

    $('#modal-content div').each(function (index) {
        $(this).html(returnString);
    });
}
```

How do I pass the values I gather from the server side click event into the javascript function?

Comment: you have it tagged as `C#` when in-fact it's `VB` have  you tried a simple google search in regards to invoking Javascript using `jquery`

Comment: @MethodMan - sorry about that I corrected it.  I have and I'm currently looking at populating a hiddenfield but I'm not liking that solution right now either.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your question is about [webform](/questions/tagged/webform). In this case try this in the aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#buttonTest").click(function () {
            $("#<%= hiddenField.ClientID%>").val("TEST");
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenField" />
<button id="buttonTest">
    Change value hidden field
</button>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="POST" ID="postButton" />
```

And this in the CodeBehind

```
Private Sub postButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles postButton.Click
    YourLogic(hiddenField.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: yes I have a solution similar to that.  However, I need the postButton to populate the data first and then open the modal window (all in 1 step).  What I'm seeing with my implementation is that I click the asp.net button the modal opens with no data until I close the window and open it again.

Comment: You can just add your function before the asp on click. I'll update the answer.